# Time conversion based on API data

Tags: php, api, time

I am trying to write a brief for a PHP page design. The page is intended to show both current times in multiple cities around the world and would also allow time conversion between different cities. The cities would be listed at the lower half of the page with a text field next to each. When a user enters time for that city in the text field, the rest of the text fields for other cities display converted time.

I was thinking of getting UTC time through an API (such as http://worldtimeapi.org/), and then based on the UTC time convert the time in-app for different cities, based on list of time zone offsets.

Could anyone please point me in a direction of how that could be achieved? In particular, I am looking at any type of a function or a process that would allow me to utilize the time data from API. I would prefer not to query the local computer for time, because the time could be misconfigured on the current computer, and I would prefer an authoritative source.

Comment: It would be inefficient to use an API every time an user enters a time. Normally you would make sure the server's clock is accurate, by synchronizing it to an authoritative source, and then use that.

Comment: Mind you, in the case an users enters a time, you don't need the current time, only the offsets from UTC.

Comment: Final thought: Offsets from UTC can vary over time. Time is complicated.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't intending to query API every time. I would query it once, on page refresh, and would track the time from there. At least that's the intent.

Comment: I would like to use the machine clock, but my concern is that this is to be run on end-user machine, and you can't rely on that clock being correct.

Comment: Using an API is a bad idea - it doesn't scale and if you can't trust your servers time then there are other problems :) PHP has all the functions you need to get the UTC time and you can statically generate the timezone offsets etc.

Comment: "but my concern is that this is to be run on end-user machine" 

PHP usually runs on a (central) server, not on an end-user machine. Can you tell us more about your use case?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use Javascript when this has to run on the on the end-user's machine.

Comment: Why using an API? Use the systemtime of the server time()
Convert it to an DateTime and then calculate the offset. I would use a database to get the offset by location.